# How to show that the change of entropy is zero for a thermally insulated system?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I am following course notes in which the formula $\frac{\partial S}{\partial V} = \frac{p}{T}$ is derived. For that, he starts from

$dS = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_V dE + \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_V dV$.

He then assumes the system is thermally insulated so that $dS = 0$. The thing is that nowhere before this result is directly justified.

After that, he plugs back the result $\frac{\partial S}{\partial V} = \frac{p}{T}$ into the equation for the variation of the entropy :

$dS = \frac{1}{T} dE + \frac{p}{T} dV$.

Finally, the identification $pdV = \delta W$ is made and the first law is used to identify

$\delta Q = T dS$.

The problem is that this is exactly the unproven assumption made earlier to assume that $dS = 0$ and justify the rest of the reasoning.

It seems a bit circular to me unless I can have an independant justification that $dS = 0$ for an insulated system. And by the way, what is a rigorous definition of "thermally insulated system" (or the contrary "thermally interacting system")?

Comment: If a system is thermally insulated, dS is not necessarily zero.  It is zero only if the thermally insulated process experienced by the system is reversible.

Comment: $dS = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_V dE + \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_V dV \rightarrow dS = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_V dE + \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_E dV$

Answer (score 2):

The assumption can be justified only if the system is in equilibrium. (However, equilibrium is usually taken as a blanket assumption in thermodynamics.)

(If the system isn't in equilibrium, there a couple ways that we could see $dS>0$. For example, if the system contains a spinning wheel in air, then the wheel will ultimately stop from friction, and the equilibrium state will be a motionless wheel in slightly warmer air, which implies $dS>0$. Alternatively, if nonreversible work is done on the system—if I whack it on the side with a hammer, for example—then entropy will also be generated as the vibrations turn into thermal energy, and $dS>0$ again.)

Heating the system would increase its entropy (by definition), but we've excluded this possibility by specifying that the system is perfectly thermally insulated. ("Thermally insulated" means that no temperature difference between the system and the environment would result in heating, i.e., a transfer of entropy. "Thermally interacting" means that such heating can occur.)

Reversible work carries no entropy. If you compressed the system at an infinitesimally slow rate, for example, then its entropy would not increase.

If a thermally insulated system is at equilibrium, therefore, the state variable entropy is stationary, indicating that $dS=0$.

You're right that this can all seem circular. That is, when we say "thermally insulated", we mean that no heating can occur, and when we say "heating", we mean $T\,dS$ energy. So it's all mutually defined at this stage. If you continue to statistical mechanics, you may find some more useful definitions. (In this context, "work" is defined as increasing the energy level of atoms, whereas "heating" is defined as increasing the breadth of their energy level distribution.)